# Bigger Action Bar and Button Android

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, styles

I'm learning how to program for Android and i have a question.

How can i do my action bar like this (which elements i have to use, etc...) :

[image]

With the text at the middle and a logo instead of the pink "+"

(I took this pic from google design and i modified it a little bit)

[image]

Comment: You may want to consider showing some examples of what you have tried, as of right now this question is too broad to expect a good answer. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I can't really show what i've tried because I'm looking the correct components to try

Answer (score 0):

In [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) go to `File > Import Sample` and type:

> Floating Action Button Basic

This is an Google's project example of what you looking for.